# How to display already created menus via php?

Tags: php, functions, menus

So I have a couple of already created menus on my wordpress installation. What I am planning to do is display navigation menus in a sliding popup. I have tried using wp_nav_menu() but it always shows the first (alphabetically) menu instead of the one I want displayed.

```
$args = array
 (
'menu_id' => $short,
'menu_class' => 'menu',
'fallback_cb' => false
 );
wp_nav_menu( $args);
```

$short is getting the menu name from the URL. As far I have understood the wp_nav_menu function I need to add code to the functions.php as well. Is that correct? I feel like in my usecase that's not the best way to solve the problem, as I want to create 25 sliding navs via PHP. If I have to add code to the functions.php as well for each menu I can do the whole  task manually.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to do the following

```
$args = array
(
'theme_location' => $short,
'menu_id' => $short,
'menu_class' => 'menu',
'menu_id'=>$menu_id,
'fallback_cb' => false
 );
wp_nav_menu( $args);
```

Theme location was the correct attribute.